# Where to put video content in website project?

Tags: html, assets, directory-structure

It's advised to put images for website in `images` folder both for good structure and SEO perspective.

And where should I put local video content? A folder called `videos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that could work. It really is up to you though.

Some prefer to make an assets folder and put their assets there and others store it in other servers. I have even known developers who literally upload it in google drive (Dont Do This)

If you are asking as a general recommendation, I suggest putting it in a folder called videos.